# Question about Alignment in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I create jFrame and put some components on it . 
I put Jpanel on it also in the left side of JFram 
when I change the size of the JFrame , the location of panel (Accourding Left Side of the JFram ) changed ...

How can I keep the same space between the panel and the left edge of JFrame
Is there Layout benefits me ??

mabey this image clears my request ..  http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b26bfdd5d7.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a layout like the GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html should tell you all you need to know.